# What's so special about a found locket in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I found a locket on a dead raider inside a large radar dish compound. When I picked it up, it gave a *special music* sound but I don't see anything in my quests that indicate I need to return it or anything.

Was it just a unique cool find, or something more special than that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This locket belongs to a quest that you probably didn't pick up yet. It's easy to miss, I recovered the locket as well before I found the quest itself.

The quest giver is located in

> Abernathy farm, west of Concord